# Can't manage to use Parse-server and vue.js

Tags: vue.js, parse-platform, vuejs3, vuetify.js, parse-server

I have a lot of troubles setting up a project that will be using parse-server, within a Vuetify 3 project.

### Steps

1. I am installing parse `npm install parse @types/parse`.
2. I create a `parse.ts` file for configuration and initialization.

```
    import Parse from 'parse';
    Parse.initialize('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY');
    Parse.serverURL = 'YOUR_PARSE_SERVER_URL';
    export default Parse;
```

3. Trying using it in a script

```
    <script lang="ts" setup>
    
    import Parse from '@/parse'; // Path to parse file
    const createTestObject = async () => {
      const TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject');
      const testObject = new TestObject();
      testObject.set('name', 'Test Name');
    
      try {
        const result = await testObject.save();
        console.log('Test object created:', result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating test object:', error);
      }
    };
    </script>
```

4. Use the component

That should be it right ?
But then I got an error `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`.

When commenting the script block, that error disappear, so it should be cause by the import.

What exactly is wrong here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that using `import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js';` instead fix this issue...

**Edit :** It fixed it in dev mode, but fails to build afterwards... So still looking for a clean solution

**Edit 2023-12-04 :** Finally found the solution, in this [thread](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/1362). Basically, the idea is to change the compiler option to add the minified file, like so :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "parse/dist/parse.min": ["node_modules/@types/parse/index.d.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```